# SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT to reject alphanumeric and special charters and allow only numeric from 0 to 9

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, check-constraint

I have the following constraint that is supposed to allow only digits from 0 to 9 insertion and not any special and alpha characters. But that is not the case, for example when using this update statement:

```
   update MyDB.dbo.MyTable 
    set MyTestPhoneExt = '23&'  where ID = 1;
```

The goal is to assure that the data being source and written to the MyTable have only digits, but the MyTestPhoneExt filed has be to **VARCHAR(15) NULL.**

```
ALTER TABLE MyDB.dbo.MyTable  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_MyDB_MyTable _MyTestPhoneExt] 
CHECK ((MyTestPhoneExt IS NULL OR LEN(MyTestPhoneExt)>=(1) AND

LEN(MyTestPhoneExt)<=(15) AND MyTestPhoneExt LIKE '%[0-9]%' 

--OR len(MyTestPhoneExt)>=(1) AND len(MyTestPhoneExt)<=(15) 

AND NOT MyTestPhoneExt LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%' 
AND NOT (MyTestPhoneExt=' ' OR MyTestPhoneExt='' OR MyTestPhoneExt='&' OR

MyTestPhoneExt='`' OR MyTestPhoneExt='~' OR MyTestPhoneExt='>' OR 

MyTestPhoneExt='<' OR MyTestPhoneExt='.' OR MyTestPhoneExt=',' OR 

MyTestPhoneExt=';' OR MyTestPhoneExt=':' OR MyTestPhoneExt='?' OR 

MyTestPhoneExt='_' OR MyTestPhoneExt='=' OR MyTestPhoneExt='+' OR

MyTestPhoneExt='!' OR MyTestPhoneExt='@' OR MyTestPhoneExt='#' OR

MyTestPhoneExt='%' OR MyTestPhoneExt='$' OR MyTestPhoneExt='^' OR

MyTestPhoneExt='*' OR MyTestPhoneExt=',' OR MyTestPhoneExt='}' OR

MyTestPhoneExt='{' OR MyTestPhoneExt=')' OR MyTestPhoneExt='(' OR 

MyTestPhoneExt=']' OR MyTestPhoneExt='[' OR MyTestPhoneExt='|' OR 

MyTestPhoneExt='\' OR MyTestPhoneExt='/' OR MyTestPhoneExt='-' OR MyTestPhoneExt='@')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using the `PATINDEX` inside the `CHECK CONSTRAINT`

```
CREATE TABLE Mytable
(
    MyCol NVARCHAR(50) CHECK(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',MyCol)=0 AND ISNUMERIC(MyCol) = 1)
)

INSERT INTO Mytable
(
    MyCol
)
VALUES(1),(2)

INSERT INTO Mytable
(
    MyCol
)
VALUES('1B'),('2A')

INSERT INTO Mytable
(
    MyCol
)
VALUES('1.0'),('2.5')


INSERT INTO Mytable
(
    MyCol
)
VALUES('1 '),('2 x')

SELECT
    *
    FROM Mytable
```

Comment: isnumeric('1,000') returns 1

Comment: Satheesh, the suggested solution looks good, but ' ' space is excepted.

Comment: INSERT INTO dbo.Mytable
(
    MyCol
)
VALUES('01 ')

Comment: I've made some more changes in the Answer and seems like it's working as expected now

Comment: Satheesh, just one more thing address it that latest changes allow empty string to be inserted into the field. And this should not be the case

Comment: I've added ISNUMERIC check also.

Comment: It did resolved the empty string issue, but another appeared. The died should be nullable, but not it does not except NULL

Comment: I fixed the NULL insertion issue. the final version of the constraint should look like:

Comment: CHECK(MyCol IS NULL OR PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',MyCol)=0 AND ISNUMERIC(MyCol) = 1)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this be a simpler way to accept only numbers?

```
patindex('%[^0-9]%', MyTestPhoneExt) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow only numerical values you could use `TRY_CONVERT()` function with *check* constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table    
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MyDB_MyTable _MyTestPhoneExt 
                         CHECK(TRY_CONVERT(BIGINT, MyTestPhoneExt) IS NOT NULL)
```

You could also use system function `ISNUMERIC()`

```
ALTER TABLE table    
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_MyDB_MyTable _MyTestPhoneExt 
                             CHECK(ISNUMERIC(MyTestPhoneExt)=1)
```

Comment: Yogesh, unfortunately, any NUMERIC data types are not an option as some of the records start with 0

Comment: Both tryconvert and isnumeric are fine for leading zeros.  isnumeric will return 1 on '1,000'